# Doctrine 2 entity field is NULL when database field contains certain special characters

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle

When fetching Doctrine 2 entity field is null because it contains "—" (&# 8212;) in database.

The field is:

```
/*
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="question", type="text", nullable=false)
 *
 * @Groups({"list", "details", "exercise_details"})
 * @Type("string")
 */

private $question;
```

And fetching is done with the following code:

```
$exercise = $exerciseRepo->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));
$this->response(json_decode($this->serializer->serialize($exercise, 'json', \JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('exercise_details', 'details')));
```

When I remove the character `—` from the database the text is displayed correctly. What could be the problem and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I just had the same problem, and I've solved it adding this line :

```
charset: UTF8
```

in config.yml

```
dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
```